# git merge driver for some of the lines

Tags: git

I have a file with many lines - some have seeds (for test seeds)
if I get conflict of those lines I want to select ours (it doesn't matter which as long as it's not the base).
After I merge all the lines with seed - I want to invoke perhaps git merge-file or git mergetool in order for them to do additional merge.
I'm failing to do it.
does someone have a pointer to an example or the skeleton of such a driver?
Currently I have a bash script that invokes the first part and according to it's exit value - invoke (or not) the git mergetool.

the problem is that git mergetool does not recognize the merge conflict markers I leave in the file.

Ideas?